# How to get the previous files based on the missing files using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to compare my array list(filename of each files inside the folder) and the log file that contains the missing files. (e.g inside the folder we have 24 files, let us say we have 01.csv, 03.csv 04.csv and 06.csv and the files missing are 02.csv and 05.csv what I want to do to copy the 01.csv or the 03.csv if the file missing is 02.csv and so on and so forth) If you have anything in mind that will make it simple. Please help!
Here is my script, what I have done so far it getting the available files inside the folder randomly to supply the missing files.

```
$folder="D:\ERM\Dump_files\Hourly\RTDEG"
$RTDEG = @("rtdeg_$RTDEG_01", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_02", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_03", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_04", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_05", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_06", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_07", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_08", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_09", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_10", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_11", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_12", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_13", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_14", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_15","rtdeg_$RTDEG_16", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_17", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_18", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_19", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_20", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_21", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_22", 
           "rtdeg_$RTDEG_23", "rtdeg_$RTDEG_24")

 $files = Get-ChildItem $folder -recurse -Exclude "*.txt", "*.log" | 
        Where-Object {($_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).adddays(-4))}

 if((Get-ChildItem "D:\ERM\Dump_files\Hourly\RTDEG" -Exclude "*.txt", 
 "*.log" | Measure-Object -line).lines -ge 24){

 echo "Viola! No missing files."

 }else{

 echo "Validating the missing files."

 $files.Basename | Out-File $folder\validation.txt

 $fileRTDEG = $files | ForEach-Object { ($_.BaseName) }

 set-Content $folder\validated.txt -value "Missing"


 Compare-Object $RTDEG $fileRTDEG | select -ExpandProperty InputObject | 
 Out- File $folder\validated.txt -Append ascii

 $compare = import-csv $folder\validated.txt

 foreach($missed in $compare){

 $data = $missed.Missing

 $random = gci $folder -Exclude "*.txt", "*.log" | where {$_.psIsContainer -     
 eq $false}| Resolve-Path | Get-Random -Count 1

 Copy-Item $random -Destination $folder\$data.csv

 }}
```

Also I wanted to make a loop to supply the arrays. But I don't think if I am doing it right. here is my code:

```
  $RTDEG = @()
  for ($i = 01; $i -le 24; $i ++){
  $date = (Get-Date).adddays(-4).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
  $list = "rtdeg_" + "" + $date + "" + $i.ToString("00")
  Write-Output $RTDEG
  }
```

Comment: For 2nd `$RTDEG =1..24|%{"rtdeg_{0}_{1}" -f $date,$_.ToString("00"}` the 1st is unclear to me.

Comment: thank you for making the 2nd more simple. 
for the 1st one, what I need is to copy 01.csv and rename it to 02.csv if the missing file is 02.csv or if 01.csv is missing it will copy the 02.csv and rename it to 01.csv